# Reports - p2sodbc.dll

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Hy,

we have IS that is also able to build, preview and print reports from data in our DB (*.rpt - crystal report).

But on one computer all reports are blank - white pages. When user connects to IS on other computer, everything is OK - so permissions are OK.

For information: we must copy 'p2sodbc.dll' into 'c:\windows\system' directory on every computer and it works (no crystal report viewer isn't installed), but no success with that particular computer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks, regards

Comment: I found a solution, it was not 'p2sodbc.dll' fault... I copied 'crpe32.dll' to 'c:\windows\system32' and now it works. Previous version was from 1997, newer is 2001.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it was not 'p2sodbc.dll' fault... I copied 'crpe32.dll' to 'c:\windows\system32' and now it works. Previous version was from 1997, newer is 2001.